# type checking of function type dose not work

Tags: typescript

I realized this code was not detected by type error.
why?

```
type Todo = {id: string}
type GetTodo = () => Todo
const getTodo: GetTodo = function() {
    return {id: "", title: ""}
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gEzlAvFA3gSwQLigZ2ACdMA7AcwF8AoUSKAcQmHiVSgAoBKVAPlkRxqAYzilCUcs1Zw8TFoPYAzAK6lhwTGO4ZqUfVCLMVRUhmx4ARJYA0UTcAA2EK5Zo0gA

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I hope to typescript detect type error because getTodo function return value is { id: string }  in type but { id: string; title: string } in implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice question and it is quite hard to explain. But I will keep it short.
It is about the Type compatibility feature.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

The `function()` itself is a anonymous function with return type `{ id: string, name: string }` but not `Todo`. It fulfils all the properties (id: string) in `Todo`, so no error occurred.

A little example:

```
type Todo =  { id: string }

// obj A has the type { id: string, name: string },
// which fulfilled all requirement in Todo, so no error
const objA =  { id: "a", name: "b" }
const obj: Todo = objA // no error, compatible with Todo
```

To enforce the return type checking, you can add the return type to the anonymous function

```
const getTodo1: GetTodo = function(): Todo {
    return {id: "", title: ""}
}
```

Here is the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-beta&ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gEzlAvFKBvKBLBAuKAZ2ACdsA7AcygF8AoUSKAcQmHiVSgAoBKVAHyxEcOnQD04qADMAruQDGwbHHJ8chKAENt5VSAC2cWZrmLlqqAHdswABZQSbWSXJRG0LLgLEyVADRQ5FoGED6kFNQ0gXrAwkh0CqrEUJRsHHAErOwiXGZKKmr8WHTo6E7ALm4Y3lAARHWBysAANmH1dfT0ElJwAEYAVlAAglB2Wpr20B6YOPhEEQFBIe2%20kbT%20PdZ22AoOci3S2C1tCNonjhAAjrLYTqHkcRTxcIGEyHpQECQkcCSJyTi-QGozQs1qdS0jWWoQIdT6dVoAPIKWBBAyXGBo0kQWQ31%20JECSQMYC0yj6bWstgcGTEOIAjCkrFoQD5IApsNIQJdKq53OBoM98hY3MA8eRpH8FNM7NAKlV%20UwxVA%20tBaUkUXE0jkkPSsulcmhhYU%20OjchhSmV5XyavMGk1bG04Z06N0cQAmchnZmsqAmaB6EgGLQtGTyAqWBAQBQtLQkMmFOjGyza%20AAETgAGZTS9MJbrdUIdDmk6Ol0gA) for reference

Comment: thank you for sharing the reference of type-compatible and describing the reason.