# Typescript type detection not working using object

Tags: typescript

```js
interface IConfig1 {
    name: string,
    age: string
}

interface IConfig2 {
    name: string
}

const config1: IConfig1 = {
    name: "123",
    age: "123"
}

var config2: IConfig2 = {
    // Type '{ age: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IConfig2'.
    // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'age' does not exist in type 'IConfig2'.(2322)
    age: "123", 
    name: "123"
}

// Why no error 
var config3: IConfig2 = config1
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2IbAOYCMyA3gLABQyVyIcAthAFzIDOYUoeANBdcnHiat2nCgF8KFUJFiIUGbLjwAmEr2q0GzNhxB5xk8gmxtkxnPgLMFFwsgC8ayhvpCARAWUBmNz2dUBd08fA3IKADc4KDNFfGVrLFtVRzJ-ZAB6dOQAFQBPAAcUAHJifkFtET0AbhpXCt08GrEi5GAWGkwwfhYWfFoAIwAbFDBMZDAC4pslZSKAOnUqTOQAeX6AKwgELsHgGThB5Do4XORsQdOWQoRgGFOAaxBMAHcQZHyoTEKoMGAIFi4-BAABNkEVAi1gZh-h0uhAAB5tLqgcaTMHTOLzAAU3mUygAlIsykFvL5kETNCSQuQJGFyMsAOoAC1OT2Q0E+0QiURiti8CViKgcvKUBAoQA)

Defining the `config2` object throws an error because the `age` does not exist in type `IConfig2`. But what confuses me is why `config3` don't throw the error `'age' does not exist in type 'IConfig2'`.

How to fix it? make `config3` throw the error.

Comment: As the error says, `Object literal` only looks for excess properties

Comment: Read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454660/type-checking-of-function-type-dose-not-work/67456804#67456804
There is a similar question i answered yesterday, it is related to type compatibility feature in typescript where IConfig1 fulfilled all requirement in and compatible with IConfig2 which has { name: string } so config3 has no error

Comment: @MicFung Thanks for your explanation, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It is called [excess-property-checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments.

In your second example:

```js
var config3: IConfig2 = config1
```

you are using object reference instead of literal, that's why excess property checking is disabled

**UPDATE**

```js
// Type for function arguments
type Strict<A, B> = keyof A extends keyof B ? keyof B extends keyof A ? A : never : never

const strict = <T, U extends Strict<T, IConfig2>>(arg: T, ...validation: T extends U ? [] : [never]) => arg
const x = strict(config2) // ok
const y = strict(config1) // expected error
```

Please keep in mind, `Strict` type just checks first level of properties. If your config object has nested properties it will not work

Comment: Thanks, how to make `config3` throw the error?

Comment: @YuMiao it is doable but it requires function overhead. Are you ok with that?